# HTML href links not working

Tags: html, list, hyperlink, href, nav

The links that I have assigned to each li does not seem to be even recognized as a link. The cursor does not even change to a hand unless I manually put the code in which is odd. The links are all background images so I can't figure out what the problem is. Please help.

```
The HTML
<div class="social_container">
<ul>

<li class="fb"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a></li>
<li class="twitter"><a href="#3"></a></li>
<li class="insta"><a href="#4"></a></li>
<li class="yt"><a href="#5"></a></li>
<li class="google"><a href="#6"></a></li>

</ul>

</div>


The CSS

.social_container ul {
      position: relative;
      top: 10%;
      width: 100%;
          padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      }

.social_container li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
       margin: 0 30px 30px 0; 
       cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
       text-align: center;

 }

.social_container li a {
          display: inline-block;
                               }


.social_container .fb {
            background: url("New Assets/FB.png") no-repeat;
            padding: 25px;
            background-size: contain;
              -webkit-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all .5s ease; 
    transition: all .5s ease;

             }

.social_container .fb:hover {

  -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -moz-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -o-transform:scale(1.2); 
     transform:scale(1.2);
}



.social_container .twitter {
            background: url("New Assets/TWITTER.png") no-repeat;
             background-size: contain;
              padding: 25px;
              -webkit-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all .5s ease; 
    transition: all .5s ease;

             }

.social_container .twitter:hover {

  -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -moz-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -o-transform:scale(1.2); 
     transform:scale(1.2);
}


.social_container .insta {
            background: url("New Assets/INSTA.png") no-repeat;
             background-size: contain;
              padding: 25px;
              -webkit-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all .5s ease; 
    transition: all .5s ease;

             }

.social_container .insta:hover {

  -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -moz-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -o-transform:scale(1.2); 
     transform:scale(1.2);
}


.social_container .yt {
            background: url("New Assets/YT.png") no-repeat;
             background-size: contain;
              padding: 25px;
              -webkit-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all .5s ease; 
    transition: all .5s ease;

             }

.social_container .yt:hover {

  -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -moz-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -o-transform:scale(1.2); 
     transform:scale(1.2);
}


.social_container .google{
            background: url("New Assets/GOOGLE.png") no-repeat;
             background-size: contain;
              padding: 25px;
              -webkit-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all .5s ease; 
    transition: all .5s ease;

             }

.social_container .google:hover {

  -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -moz-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2); 
    -o-transform:scale(1.2); 
     transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: It seems to work fine... https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/bb630jbt/ (all I did was add a color since the images won't load).

Comment: Try adding &nbsp; between <a> here </a>

Comment: Ok thanks to whoever it was before, I moved <a> outside of the <li> and it works.

Comment: @LordEwwLel you really **should not** move the anchor outside the li tags.. that is **not** valid HTML markup. As my fiddle in the comment above points out... what you've posted here works fine. There *must* be some other issue with your CSS that is causing this. Hobbling together a "patch" to make this one thing function with invalid HTML will surely result in the problem remaining and possibly other issues.

Comment: I'll check the rest of my code, thanks for the warning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="social_container">
<ul>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><li class="fb"> Face Book </li></a>
<a href="#3"><li class="twitter"> 3 </li></a>
<a href="#4"><li class="insta"> 4 </li></a>
<a href="#5"><li class="yt"> 5 </li></a>
<a href="#6"><li class="google"> Google </li></a>

</ul>

</div>
```

its better to link your `<li>`

example: https://jsfiddle.net/TiG3R/u4w2v9q5/

Comment: linking <li> seems to fix it

Comment: **This is NOT valid markup**... `ul` tags can not contain anchor tags as direct children.

Comment: he can remove `ul` tag and use `.social_container li` for css

Comment: You **can't** "remove the ul tag" if you want to use list items (`li` tags). In addition, this change isn't necessary at all:  https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/bb630jbt/ it works fine, there's *some other issue* with the user markup, it's not a problem with the markup the user posted.

Comment: but i always remove ul tag and link my li and its work fine xD , i do this many time

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add anything between

```
<a> and </a>

<div class="social_container">
<ul>

<li class="fb"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a></li>
<li class="twitter"><a href="#3">something needs to be here</a></li>
<li class="insta"><a href="#4">something needs to be here</a></li>
<li class="yt"><a href="#5">something needs to be here</a></li>
<li class="google"><a href="#6">something needs to be here</a></li>

</ul>
```

Also, just out of curiosity, why add the div? Why not:

```
<ul class="social_container">
  <li>
    <a>...</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```